# Can I regenerate blkindex.dat from blk0001.dat?

Tags: blockchain, database

My copy of `blkindex.dat` became corrupted, but I still have the whole `blk0001.dat` file.

Is it possible to reconstruct the `blkindex.dat` file from the `blk0001.dat` file or do I have to delete both files and redownload the whole blockchain from scratch?

Edit: Pieter's answer is working for me.  It's taking many hours to run, but at least it isn't using any bandwidth.  I'm wondering, as a related question, whether this `bitcoind -loadblock=blk0001.dat.bak` technique is a way of being able to get a trusted copy of the blockchain from an untrusted source.  If I download a blk0001.dat from a random website, then import it using this -loadblock command, does that ensure it's correct, and ask the network for anything the download was missing?

While running, the command just said:

```
SetBestChain: new best=00000000000004411998  height=174305  work=284206530118085534778
SetBestChain: new best=00000000000009a01d64  height=174306  work=284213516218692473063
InvalidChainFound: invalid block=000000000000038181de  height=174307  work=284220502319299411348
InvalidChainFound:  current best=00000000000009a01d64  height=174306  work=284213516218692473063
SetBestChain: new best=00000000000007e352ec  height=174307  work=284220502319299411348
SetBestChain: new best=00000000000006b4b91c  height=174308  work=284227488419906349633
```

Is that normal, representing an orphaned block?  Or possibly the result of the same disk error that caused the `blkindex.dat` to become corrupted initially?

Comment: (because I don't want to redownload the whole blockchain over this 3G connection)

Comment: Seems unlikely that it's caused by the disk error. I see no way to recover from a corrupted block that's part of the main chain, since all later blocks depend on it.

Comment: It looks like I had two different blocks at height 174307 though - see how the hashes are different?  All later blocks only depend on one of them.  Incidentally, the -loadblock command hung after about 6 hours, with around 8000 blocks still to import.  I quit it and ended up going back to the partially completed download I had been running before, which only had about 2000 blocks missing.

Comment: Orphan (in the meaning of "without parent") blocks are never stored on disk, just cached in RAM until their parents are fetched. This seems to be a stale block (one not (anymore) in the main chain) that got corrupted; it is certainly not normal to have stale blocks that cause invalid chains.

Comment: I just remembered; the number 174307 looks familiar to me. I believe this was a BP16-invalid block that got created shortly after the switch, before many nodes updated. Getting an invalid chain error during re-import is expected behavior in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible in git HEAD, and will be in 0.7.0. You can move the existing blk0001.dat elsewhere, delete blkindex.dat, and then start the client using `./bitcoind -loadblock=blk0001.dat.bak`

Comment: That's working nicely, thanks.  One thing I noticed is that while it's importing from the .bak file the splash screen says "Loading wallet..." which is a little misleading.  (I use 'bitcoin-qt -server' rather than 'bitcoind')

Comment: I added to my question as the -loadblock=... is running.

Comment: my blk0001.dat corrupts all the time.