# How can I recover from a corrupted blkindex.dat on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: block, ubuntu

I've installed Bitcoin-Qt after a clean WUBI install, and installed Bitcoin-Qt directly. Now it suddenly says "Error loading `blkindex.dat`".

I assume my `blkindex.dat` file is corrupted, and I tried reinstalling Bitcoin-Qt with `apt` but it didn't work. Maybe if I delete the `blkindex.dat` file it will try to create it again, but I don't know where the installation folder is.

How can I solve this issue?

Extra information (added by other user); the error will likely look like this:

```
file blkindex.dat has LSN 727/2518588, past end of log at 727/1519938
Commonly caused by moving a database from one database environment
to another without clearing the database LSNs, or by removing all of
the log files from a database environment
__db_meta_setup: /home/user/.bitcoin/blkindex.dat: unexpected file type or format
```

You should be able to find this in `~/.bitcoin/db.log`. This problem occured when interrupting the client suddenly or maybe because two of them opened the database at the same time.

Comment: I have this problem all the time. I just erase blk* but it will take 2 days long to download all blockchain again. I don't know why it is happening. I think it is a problem of the recent version.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, the Bitcoin client data is kept in the `.bitcoin` directory in your home directory. Go to `~/.bitcoin/` and you'll see the files in there. You may need to toggle Show Hidden Files in your file manager in order to see the directory.

If you remove `blkindex.dat`, the client will have to redownload the blockchain. I just tested this locally by moving my copy of the file to another file name temporarily - the client resync'd.

Since your copy of the index is corrupted apparently, it sounds like you need to delete it and resync.

*A note: be careful to do not erase your `wallet.dat`. I recommend you back it up before. Your `wallet.dat` is your private keys.*

Answer (score 6):

Just run `./bitcoind -reindex` and this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to redownload everything from the p2p network, which may be slow as you have to validate the whole chain, you can download the bootstrap chain file [from bitcoincharts.com](http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/)

It is also available through bittorrent, which may be faster for you. Here's a copy of the message posted above and in the [forums](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=117982.0) that authenticate the file (through GPG).

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1


Torrent info hash: 0bb0521942f586ed96203c6f4d136324756f8a9a
Torrent magnet link:
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0bb0521942f586ed96203c6f4d136324756f8a9a&dn=bootstrap.dat

Filename: bootstrap.dat
Byte size: 2491771562
SHA1: e70ca90775dfdb13fd0014425805a0bdf4a31677
SHA256: a3f258e7af030165360596e4cb0b9beb24b4ce97352c22e65349b89ad5fc5d3e

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.12 (GNU/Linux)
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=uwRB
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Also, here's a magnet link that includes trackers:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0bb0521942f586ed96203c6f4d136324756f8a9a&dn=bootstrap.dat&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.ccc.de:80&tr=udp://tracker.istole.it:80
```

Finally, as explained in [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/can-i-regenerate-blkindex-dat-from-blk0001-dat), you can also simply discard the index and regenerate it using the existing ondisk `blk000?.dat` files, using `-loadblock=blk0001.dat` and by deleting `blkindex.dat`.

Edit: note that with bitcoind 0.8 and up, it's actually easier and faster to just download the block chain from the network directly, so don't bother with the bittorrent/manual download.