# bitcoind: corrupted database?

Tags: bitcoind

```
looris@Palace-of-the-Nine-Moons:/tmp $ bitcoind 
looris@Palace-of-the-Nine-Moons:/tmp $ Bitcoin server starting


************************
EXCEPTION: St13runtime_error       
CLevelDB(): error opening database environment Corruption: missing start of fragmented record(2)       
bitcoin in AppInit()
```

This happens when I start `bitcoind`, any clue on what could I do to fix it?

I tried to run it with `-rescan` but the result was the same.

Comment: I suspect it would be faster to redownload the blockchain than fix this, but [here's where your error is being thrown from](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/leveldb.cpp#L57)

Comment: @NickODell doing it, but it takes me more than 24h to download it all, if this bug happens again I'd really need a quicker way to fix it...

Comment: Agreed. Actually, [this](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/leveldb/db/log_reader.cc#L124) seems more relevant to your problem. It would appear that if it loads a record of type kLastType which isn't preceeded by kFirstType, then it will put out that error message.

Comment: @NickODell oh thank you, that would be useful. Now I'm re-downloading anyway, but I've not deleted the corrupted db yet...

Comment: You need -reindex, not -rescan (which is for finding missing wallet transactions).

Answer (score 4):

Just run `./bitcoind -reindex` and this will fix your problem.

`-rescan` is for missing wallet transactions

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in the `~/.bitcoin/db.log` file for more information. It is likely that your only solution is to remove the block database (either `blk0001.dat`,  `blk0002.dat` or `blkindex.dat`). **DO NOT REMOVE YOUR** `wallet.dat` file!!!

This means you will have to download the whole block chain again. [This other question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5876/how-can-i-recover-from-a-corrupted-blkindex-dat-on-ubuntu-12-10) has tips on how to speed up that download.

Note that this may just be another case of the question asked [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5876/how-can-i-recover-from-a-corrupted-blkindex-dat-on-ubuntu-12-10).

Comment: Don't advise people to wipe their data directories. Since 0.8, we have -reindex which rebuilds them without redownloading.